# PhpStorm run single test by clicking on the test method

Tags: testing, phpstorm

I have just seen a video where a PHPUnit test was run by clicking the method name. I assume that it is necessary to also press a button while clicking. I am only aware of the `Ctrl+Click` shortcut to find usages of the method.

What do I have to press in order to run the test?

Comment: Give us a link to such video. I'm not aware of such "simple click" that will run a test. Although there are ways to speed up running specific test/method instead of whole file.

Comment: @LazyOne It is on LaraCasts member area. So you probably will not be able to access it without an account:
https://laracasts.com/series/phpunit-testing-in-laravel/episodes/15

Comment: Yeah :( I do not have an account there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you place caret on method in PHPUnit test file, pressing "Run" shortcut will allow to choose to run only this method. Once configuration is created, it will be launched automatically so you just place the caret and trigger "Run" action.
There's also "Run Context Configuration" action/shortcut which quickly brings you to creating a configuration for method and running it without selecting from available options first.

Comment: Do you literally have to type a `^` (carrot) before the function? This is giving me a syntax error.